# REDUX-TOOLKIT: not update the state simultaneously

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

I am working on a project with redux-toolkit. When I create my slice, state not udating simultaneouly. Here is my slice:

```
export const currentTabSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'currentTab',
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    currentTabUpdate: (state, action) => {
      const newState = Object.assign(state, action.payload)
      state = newState
    },
  },
})
export const { currentTabUpdate } = currentTabSlice.actions
export default currentTabSlice.reducer
export const selectCurrentTab = (state) => {
  console.log('slice en alttaki fun state', state)
  return state
}
```

Also, I write reducer as `state = action.payload`  (With this version it never updates.)

Maybe you want to see my store:

```
let sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

const localStorage = createLocalStorage()
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: localStorage,
}

const reducers = combineReducers({
  currentTab: currentTabReducer,
  
})

const createPersistReducer = (config) => persistReducer(config, reducers)

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: createPersistReducer(persistConfig),
  middleware: [sagaMiddleware],
})

sagaMiddleware.run(watchNS3request)

export default store
```